# Update/Edit of Hibernate Entities is not working properly

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, selenium

I tried all combinations of cascade types on `Team` and `TeamMembers` but still unable to update/edit given `TeamMember` using manual/Selenium tests. The problem seems to be with hibernate:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.sprhib.model.TeamMember#1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.sprhib.model.TeamMember#1]] with root cause
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.sprhib.model.TeamMember#1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:676)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:584)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:515)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.updateTeamMember(Unknown Source)
    at com.sprhib.controller.TeamMemberController.editingTeamMember(TeamMemberController.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Basically all update/edit operations are not working. I need all UI test to pass. [My project][1]. Maybe there are some design issues I am not aware of... What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

```
import com.sprhib.model.Team;
import com.sprhib.model.TeamMember;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class TeamMemberDAOImpl implements TeamMemberDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    private Session openSession(){
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public void addTeamMember(TeamMember teamMember) {
        Iterator<Team> iterator = teamMember.getTeams().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Team t = iterator.next();
            Team team = (Team) getCurrentSession().get(Team.class, t.getId());

            Set<TeamMember> teamMembers = team.getTeamMembers();
            teamMembers.add(teamMember);
        }
    }

    public void updateTeamMember(TeamMember teamMember) {
        // get all teams related to teamMember
        // for each team:
        //      if team doesn't have this team member then add
        synchronized (this){
            Iterator<Team> iteratorTeams = teamMember.getTeams().iterator();
            while(iteratorTeams.hasNext()){
                Team t = iteratorTeams.next();
                Team team = (Team) getCurrentSession().get(Team.class, t.getId());

                Set<TeamMember> teamMembers = team.getTeamMembers();
                if(!teamMembers.contains(teamMember)){
                    teamMembers.add(teamMember);
                }
            }

        }


//        no errors but teams is not updated
        /*TeamMember tm = getTeamMember(teamMember.getId());
        tm.setName(teamMember.getName());
        tm.setTeams(teamMember.getTeams());*/
    }

    public TeamMember getTeamMember(int id) {
        TeamMember teamMember = (TeamMember) getCurrentSession().get(TeamMember.class, id);
        return teamMember;
    }

    public void deleteTeamMember(int id) {
        if(getTeamMember(id) != null){
            getCurrentSession().delete(getTeamMember(id));
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<TeamMember> getTeamMembers() {
        return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from TeamMember").list();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2**

**merge()** solved the problem.

Comment: What about the NonUniqueObjectException?

Comment: @RCola  Can you please post body of the method() where all you using Transaction annotaion..!!

Comment: I cannot update existing entities correctly. I can update Organization which has `OneToMany`. But impossible to do the same with `TeamMember` and `Team` that has `ManyToMany` relationships between each other. All kind of exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this below code it may work am not sure..

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=false)
public void updateTeamMember(TeamMember teamMember) {
    // get all teams related to teamMember
    // for each team:
    //      if team doesn't have this team member then add
    synchronized (this){
        Iterator<Team> iteratorTeams = teamMember.getTeams().iterator();
        while(iteratorTeams.hasNext()){
            Team t = iteratorTeams.next();
            Team team = (Team) getCurrentSession().get(Team.class, t.getId());

            Set<TeamMember> teamMembers = team.getTeamMembers();
            if(!teamMembers.contains(teamMember)){
                teamMembers.add(teamMember);

                getCurrentSession().merge(teamMember); // IMPORTANT!
                getCurrentSession().merge(team); // IMPORTANT!
            }
        }

    }

    TeamMember tm = getTeamMember(teamMember.getId());
    tm.setName(teamMember.getName());
    tm.setTeams(teamMember.getTeams());
}
```

Comment: With some records it just doing fine. But with some it is  throwing `org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.sprhib.model.TeamMember#3]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.sprhib.model.TeamMember#3]`

Comment: Probably there has to be `merge()` for `TeamMember` but how to know when to merge?

Comment: When an  new entity is to be persist into Database then persist() is used and when an existing entity that is an entity which is fetched form Database need to be update then merge() is used. But merge() can also be used for persisting new entity. Check that are you trying to update or persist the entity and which method you using for persisting and updating.